# How to get back storyboard in xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2, storyboard

Everyone.

I was trying to develop one application containing navigation control n view controller.
But by mistake I deleted the iPhone story board.
Can any one help me to get back it again.

thanks in advance.